# Prevent Office 365 Active Directory users from changing password

Tags: powershell, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I need to prevent users created on the active directory of our Office 365 business account to change the password into their Office 365 Web Interface. I was trying to use Active Directory module from Windows PowerShell with the following command:

```
Set-ADAccountControl -Identity JaneDow -CannotChangePassword $true
```

But I got an exception "Set-ADAccountControl : Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running."

Is there another way to get rid of the password change ability in office 365?

Comment: If your users sync from on-prem AD, we can use local AD to set "user cannot change passwd", If your users just create in AAD, as far as I know, we can't do it for now.

Comment: Thanks, yes basically I had to synchronise AD on premises with the Office 365 cloud users in order to remove the pwd change ability on office 365 online UI.